# Does block parameters need to specify ownership qualifiers when providing weak references?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to use blocks in a way where I provide a reference to the object which retains the block, as follows:

```
typedef void(^RunBlock)(__weak Thing *block_owner, ThingFinishBlock finish);
```

where `Thing` has a property `run_block`, of the type `RunBlock`.

```
Thing *thing = [Thing thingWithBlock^(Thing *owner, ThingFinishBlock finish) { ... }];
```

Calling the `run_block` from within the `Thing` goes something like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) this = self;
_finish_block = ^(){ ... }
self.run_block(this, _finish_block);
```

So what I'm wondering now is, is it safe to define the `run_block`'s first parameter `Thing *owner` without prefixing it with `__weak`, or will this cause a retain loop? I'm unsure, as the pointer is already defined as `__weak` in the typedef, and the given parameter is already `__weak`.

```
^(__weak Thing *owner ...){ ... }
```

As opposed to

```
^(Thing *owner, ...) { ... }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, `__weak` in parameters is not part of the function type itself.

```
typedef void(^RunBlock)(__weak Thing *block_owner, ThingFinishBlock finish);
```

is the same as

```
typedef void(^RunBlock)(Thing *block_owner, ThingFinishBlock finish);
```

It's where you implement the block that the `__weak` in the parameter matters.

Also, I have no idea why you think this has anything to do with retain cycles.